# angular 2 how to pass service response data to UI

Tags: angular

i am fairly new to angular 2. and stuck on a basic problem.

my component showing ui is like:
**chat.ts**

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-chat',
  templateUrl: 'chat.html',
  providers: [ChatService]
})
export class ChatPage {
 items: SimpleMessage[] = [];

createChatBubble(chatMessage: string){
    //alert(this.chatMessage);
     this.items.push(new SimpleMessage(chatMessage));
  }
}
```

**chat-service.ts**

```
        @Injectable()

            export class ChatService {
            openSocket(){
                this.ws = new WebSocket('ws://' + this.host + '/chat/ws');
                this.ws.addEventListener('message', event => {
                  this.zone.run(() => {
                    var msg = JSON.parse(event.data);
                    this.broadcast(msg);
                  });
                });


  broadcast(msg){
      let message = this.parseModel(msg);
      let chatReply = new SimpleMessage(message, 'bot');
    }
}
```

So, the message received from server in the broadbast function needs to be passed to the chat.ts items object somehow. Please advise

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service with an observable to which you subscribe to from the components.

EDIT:
I wrote another example.
I'm not going to write a socket, but I wrote a child component which triggers some event on a button click. The whole app can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/LUS1N/service-example).

Service

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class CommunicateService {

  // source of change
  private newStringSource = new Subject<string>();

  // observable
  public stringCreated = this.newStringSource.asObservable();

  public sendNewString(newString: string): void {
    // broadcasts the new data to every listener
    this.newStringSource.next(newString);
  }
}
```

App component

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {CommunicateService} from './communicate.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<h1>
    {{title}}
    <app-child></app-child>
  </h1>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'app works!';


  constructor(private communicateService: CommunicateService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.communicateService.stringCreated.subscribe(event => {
      console.log(event);
    });
  }
}
```

Child with a button trigger

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {CommunicateService} from '../communicate.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `<p>
    child works!
    <button (click)="onClick()"> Click me </button>
  </p>
  `
})
export class ChildComponent {

  constructor(private communicateService: CommunicateService) {
  }

  onClick() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      this.communicateService.sendNewString(`i is ${i}`); // string interpolation
  }
}
```

So what you want to do is instead of injecting the service into the child comp here, inject it into the socket service and call sendNewString when you receive new data.

Hope it helps.

Comment: are both componentChangeSource and newDateCreationSource required or just two different variations?

Comment: Just different variations, to display that there doesn't necessarily need to be some data passed.

Comment: where is componentChanged$ declared in service?  what that $ means in the end?

Comment: I made the documentation from the angular.io docs, I think the $ is just a convention for source or something. It is declared there in the service where you see it, the default modifier is public therefore can be omitted, its the same if it was ```public  componentChanged$ = this.componentChangeSource.asObservable();```

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service 
I think the $ means that its ```Observable```

Comment: ok got confused as there was not type either. we declare like <modfier> type <name>;

Comment: In typescript its <modifier> name : <type>

Comment: still having some issues in understanding it overall. can there be a minimal example to see it in action.